# Android Google Maps dynamic fragment in RecyclerView holder

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to add Google Maps fragments into a RecyclerView in Android.

I was reading about it and I saw that I need to create the fragments dynamically instead of doing it by XML to avoid the duplicate ID errors.

Here is my **adapter code**:

```
public class MapViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected FrameLayout mapContainer;

    public MapViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        view = v;
        mapContainer = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
    }
}

private void bindMapRow(final MapViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageData message = (MessageData) messagesList.get(position);
        LocationData location = message.getLocation();

        FrameLayout view = holder.mapContainer;
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context);
        if (message.getIdMap() != 0) {
            frame.setId(message.getIdMap());
        }
        else {
            message.setIdMap(generateViewId());
            frame.setId(message.getIdMap());
            messagesList.set(position, message);
        }

        int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.row_chat_map_size);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
        frame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        view.addView(frame);

        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.liteMode(true);

        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(new MapReadyCallback(location));

        FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(frame.getId(), mapFrag);
        ft.commit();
}
```

Executing this I can see the map displayed into my RecyclerView and all seems to be working well. 
The problem appears when I scroll up in the RecyclerView for a while and then I go back again to the map.

When I do that the app crashes and shows this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1 (unknown)
>   for fragment SupportMapFragment{606864b #0 id=0x1}

Many thanks and kind regards,
Marcel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `bindMapRow` is called at `onBindViewHolder`.

The reason for the error `IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id` is that `holder.mapContainer` and `frame` is not attached to the RecyclerView/Activity yet during `onBindViewHolder` (thus the view not found error).

To guarantee the view is already attached to RecyclerView/Activity before calling `FragmentTransaction.replace`, listen to `onViewAttachedToWindow` instead.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

        // If you have multiple View Type, check for the correct viewType 
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = holder.mapFragment;
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    ...
                }
            });
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/supportmapfragment-in-recyclerview/